MASM x86 program printing random symbols
I was trying to run my assembly language program written in MASM x86 when I found that every time when I print out my receipt, all burgers are printed with random symbols behind them. The original idea was to print out only the burger with quantity > 0, and then display their price per unit and quantity ordered in the next line. My code is attached as below. I suspect it's some sort of a  logic error but I couldn't spot where is the error.
scan_burger PROC
    
    CMP burger_quantity[0], 0
    JLE detect_burger_quantity_A
    
    CALL display_burger1

detect_burger_quantity_A:
    CMP burger_quantity[1], 0
    JLE detect_burger_quantity_B
    
    CALL display_burger2
    
detect_burger_quantity_B:
    CMP burger_quantity[2], 0
    JLE detect_burger_quantity_C
    
    CALL display_burger3
    
detect_burger_quantity_C:
    CMP burger_quantity[3], 0
    JLE return_scan_burger
    
    CALL display_burger4

return_scan_burger:
    ret
    
scan_burger ENDP

display_burger1 PROC
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_1_name
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, next_line
    INT 21H
    
    XOR AX, AX
    
    MOV AL, burger_quantity[0]
    DIV ten
    MOV Q1, AL
    MOV R1, AH
    
    ADD Q1, '0'
    ADD R1, '0'
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, Q1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, R1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, space
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_price[0]
    INT 21H
    
display_burger1 ENDP

display_burger2 PROC

    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_2_name
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, next_line
    INT 21H
    
    XOR AX, AX
    
    MOV AL, burger_quantity[1]
    DIV ten
    MOV Q1, AL
    MOV R1, AH
    
    ADD Q1, '0'
    ADD R1, '0'
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, Q1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, R1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, space
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_price[1]
    INT 21H
    
display_burger2 ENDP

display_burger3 PROC

    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_3_name
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, next_line
    INT 21H
    
    XOR AX, AX
    
    MOV AL, burger_quantity[2]
    DIV ten
    MOV Q1, AL
    MOV R1, AH
    
    ADD Q1, '0'
    ADD R1, '0'
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, Q1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, R1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, space
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_price[2]
    INT 21H

display_burger3 ENDP

display_burger4 PROC

    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_4_name
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, next_line
    INT 21H
    
    XOR AX, AX
    
    MOV AL, burger_quantity[3]
    DIV ten
    MOV Q1, AL
    MOV R1, AH
    
    ADD Q1, '0'
    ADD R1, '0'
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, Q1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV DL, R1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, space
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, burger_price[3]
    INT 21H
    
display_burger4 ENDP



You are using function code 09H to print single characters. But that value is used to print a string which is why you get the garabge. Change it to use 02H to print just the charactger in register DL.

Thank you for noticing that ! I didnt realize that i typed 09H instead of 02H, it did fix the random symbols
